# JSTL Iterate over 2 datasets?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

This might be a easy one.  I currently have 1 dataset in a forEach and would like to iterate over a second one at the same time?   Is this possible?

```
<c:set value="${dataList}" var="beans" />
<c:set value="${newDataList}" var="newBeans"/>

<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="loopCount">
```

Comment: Is `dataList.size()` always equal to `newDataList.size()`?

Comment: yes they both are the same size....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the collections are always equal in size, you can loop through one and access the second based on index.

```
<c:forEach var="bean" items="${beans}" varStatus="loopCount">
  <c:out value="${bean}" /> <c:out value="${newBeans[loopCount.index]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Im about to give that a try,,,,,,,,